# "Set Difference" between two vectors with duplicate values

Tags: r

I have 3 vectors

```
x <- c(1,3,5,7,3,8)
y <- c(3,5,7)
z <- c(3,3,8)
```

I want to find the elements of `x` that are not in `y` and not in `z`. Is there a function `f` that would give me the following output:

```
> f(x,y)
1 3 8
> f(x,z)
1 5 7
```

In other words, I want to find the "set difference" between 2 vectors, either of which may have repeated values. The functions `%in%`, `match` and `setdiff` do not work in this case for obvious reasons.

Comment: You say you want the difference between 2 vectors, but you present 3 vectors...

Comment: The problem only involves 2 vectors. The vectors `y` and `z` are used for separate cases. `z` contains duplicates, while `y` does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be some better ways to do this but here is one option

```
get_diff_vectors <- function(x, y) {
  count_x <- table(x)
  count_y <- table(y)
  same_counts <- match(names(count_y), names(count_x))
  count_x[same_counts] <- count_x[same_counts] - count_y
  as.numeric(rep(names(count_x), count_x))
}

get_diff_vectors(x, y)
#[1] 1 3 8
get_diff_vectors(x, z)
#[1] 1 5 7
get_diff_vectors(x, c(5, 7))
#[1] 1 3 3 8
```

We count the frequency of `x` and `y` using `table`, `match` the numbers which occur in both and subtract the counts `y` from `x`. Finally recreate the remaining vector using `rep`.

---

Still not able to find a better way but here is `dplyr` way using the somewhat similar logic.

```
library(dplyr)

get_diff_vectors_dplyr <- function(x, y) {
  df1 <- data.frame(x) %>% count(x)
  df2 <- data.frame(y) %>% count(y)
  final <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("x" = "y")) %>%
           mutate_at(c("n.x", "n.y"), funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0))) %>%
           mutate(n = n.x - n.y)

  rep(final$x, final$n)
}

get_diff_vectors_dplyr(x, y)
#[1] 1 3 8
get_diff_vectors_dplyr(x, z)
#[1] 1 5 7
get_diff_vectors_dplyr(x, c(5, 7))
#[1] 1 3 3 8
```

---

The `vecsets` package mentioned by OP has function `vsetdiff` which does this very easily

```
vecsets::vsetdiff(x, y)
#[1] 1 3 8
vecsets::vsetdiff(x, z)
#[1] 1 5 7
vecsets::vsetdiff(x, c(5, 7))
#[1] 1 3 3 8
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, thanks, but I've found a package `vecsets` that does exactly what I'm looking for. I will accept this answer though.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an attempt using `make.unique` to account for duplicates:

```
dupdiff <- function(x,y) x[-match(
  make.unique(as.character(y)),
  make.unique(as.character(x)),
  nomatch=0
)]
```

Testing:

```
dupdiff(x,y)
#[1] 1 3 8
dupdiff(x,z)
#[1] 1 5 7
dupdiff(x, c(5, 7))
#[1] 1 3 3 8
dupdiff(x, c(5, 7, 9))
#[1] 1 3 3 8
```

Answer (score 2):

`match` with a little for-loop does work:

```
> f(x, y)
[1] 1 3 8
> f(x, z)
[1] 1 5 7
```

#### Code

```
f <- function(s, r) {
    for(i in 1:length(s)){
        j <- match(s[i], r)
        if(!is.na(j)) {
            s[i] <- NA
            r[j] <- NA
        } 
    }
    print(s[complete.cases(s)])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the new Hadley-verse package `waldo`

Makes real nice and concise overviews of the differences of objects, not only vectors

```r
library(waldo)

compare(x, y)
#> `old`: 1 3 5 7 3 8
#> `new`:   3 5 7
compare(x, z)
#> `old`: 1 3 5 7 3 8
#> `new`:   3     3 8
```

Comment: Is this comparison only for display purposes ? Can we not somehow use these values ?

Comment: @RonakShah good question. I think its main purpose is display indeed. I think its still worth to point this package out, in particular as the OP did not particularly specify their intention when asking to "find the differences". On the other hand, (not at a console right now), I am sure waldo::compare returns an object that can be explored for the values. Will update on that once I am back on R.

Comment: @RonakShah see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64806192/how-to-extract-outstanding-values-from-an-object-returned-by-waldocompare)

Comment: @user63230 thanks that’s very interesting

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `table`.

```
f <- function(a, b) {x <- split(seq_along(a), a)
    y <- table(b)
    . <- names(y)[names(y) %in% names(x)]
    x[.] <- Map(tail, x[.], -y[.])
    a[sort(unlist(x))] } #Without sort when order does not matter

f(x,y)
#[1] 1 3 8
f(x,z)
#[1] 1 5 7
```

In case the order does not matter and using `unique` `factor` and `table`.

```
f2 <- function(a, b) {u <- unique(a)
  . <- table(factor(a, u)) - table(factor(b, u))
  i <- which(.>0)
  rep(u[i], .[i]) }

f2(x,y)
#[1] 1 3 8
f2(x,z)
#[1] 1 5 7
```

Or using `tapply`:

```
f3 <- function(a, b) {
    . <- unlist(tapply(b, b, function(x) head(which(x[1] == a), length(x))))
    if(length(.) > 0) a[-.] else a }

f3(x,y)
#[1] 1 3 8
f3(x,z)
#[1] 1 5 7
```

To show difference between both.

```
x <- c(5, 3, 1, 3)
y <- c(3, 9)

f(x, y)
#[1] 5 1 3

f2(x, y)
#[1] 1 3 5

f3(x, y)
#[1] 5 1 3
```

---

Benchmark

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e5
x <- sample(1:(n/10), n, TRUE)
y <- sample(1:(n/10), n, TRUE)

dupdiff <- function(x,y) x[-match(  #@thelatemail
  make.unique(as.character(y)),
  make.unique(as.character(x)),
  nomatch=0
)]

library(data.table)  #@jblood94
dtDiff <- function(a, b) data.table(a, rowid(a))[!data.table(b, rowid(b)), on = .(a = b, V2)][[1]]

forDif <- function(s, r) {  #@Roman
    for(i in 1:length(s)){
        j <- match(s[i], r)
        if(!is.na(j)) {
            s[i] <- NA
            r[j] <- NA
        } 
    }
    s[complete.cases(s)]
}

bench::mark(check=FALSE, split=f(x,y), table=f2(x,y), tapply =f3(x,y),
            make.unique=dupdiff(x,y), vecsets = vecsets::vsetdiff(x, y),
            data.dable = dtDiff(x,y), "for" = forDif(x,y) )
```

Result

```
  expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc gc/se…¹ n_itr  n_gc total_…²
  <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:tm>
1 split        77.81ms  84.25ms   12.0      13.45MB   14.0      6     7 501.31ms
2 table        34.52ms  38.24ms   20.6      13.37MB    7.50    11     4    533ms
3 tapply          2.2s     2.2s    0.454     7.46GB   99.5      1   219     2.2s
4 make.unique 106.72ms 108.46ms    9.23     11.38MB    3.69     5     2 541.86ms
5 vecsets        2.45s    2.45s    0.408     7.46GB   85.6      1   210    2.45s
6 data.dable    7.91ms   8.72ms   99.6      11.64MB   37.9     50    19 501.94ms
7 for           14.89s   14.89s    0.0672   37.26GB   65.5      1   975   14.89s
```