# Ordering rows in a data.table in a specific order

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following data.table in R:

```
col_1  col_2
    c      1
    c      1
    d      1
    b      1
    a      1
    b      1
```

How would I use data.table functions to reorder rows in the particular order, c("b", "c", "b", "c", "a", "d"), so that the resulting data table will be the following?

```
col_1  col_2
    b      1
    c      1
    b      1
    c      1
    a      1
    d      1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using `make.unique`:

```
x <- make.unique(c("b", "c", "b", "c", "a", "d"))
DT[match(x, make.unique(col_1))]
```

output:

```
   col_1 col_2
1:     b     1
2:     c     1
3:     b     1
4:     c     1
5:     a     1
6:     d     1
```

Reference:
I came across `make.unique` here:
["Set Difference" between two vectors with duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941312/set-difference-between-two-vectors-with-duplicate-values/52942117#52942117)

Comment: Wow, this is such a simple and elegant solution!  I thought I had to use factor().  I didn't even know about the make.unique function until now.  I'm glad to learn about this nice base function.  Thanks a lot!