# How to output the additional elements added to a vector in R

Tags: r

If I have 2 vectors of length 7 and 4 respectively (in R),

```
vec1 <- c(1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0)


vec2 <- c(1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0)
```

I want to output a vector that shows the elements added to vec2 in order to create vec1

```
output <- c(1.0, 3.0, 4.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `vsetdiff` from `vecsets`

```
library(vecsets)
vsetdiff(vec1, vec2)
#[1] 1 4 3
```

NOTE: With float/double, there would be a precision involved.  That needs to be considered while using `vsetdiff`

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using `base R`:

```
get_diff_vectors <- function(x, y) {
  count_x <- table(vec1)
  count_y <- table(vec2)
  same_counts <- match(names(count_y), names(count_x))
  count_x[same_counts] <- count_x[same_counts] - count_y
  as.numeric(rep(names(count_x), count_x))
}

output <- get_diff_vectors(vec1, vec2)
```

Which returns:

```
[1] 1 3 4
```

Taken directly from this post, credit to Ronak Shah: ["Set Difference" between two vectors with duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941312/set-difference-between-two-vectors-with-duplicate-values)