# Perform set operations on duplicate items, in R (base R preferably)

Tags: r, set

So, I have a very basic question, for which I tried to find answers on existing questions but in vain.

Q:  How can I calculate `setdiff` together with considering duplicate elements?

```
x <- c(1:4, 1)

> x
[1] 1 2 3 4 1
> length(x)
[1] 5

y <- 1
> length(y)
[1] 1

setdiff(x, y)
[1] 2 3 4

> length(setdiff(x,y))
[1] 3
```

I want a return value of `1, 2, 3, 4` as only one `1` should be removed from x.  Is it possible somehow in baseR?

Comment: `vecsets::vsetdiff(x, y)` is the easiest. There are also couple of base R answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941312/set-difference-between-two-vectors-with-duplicate-values

Comment: Thanks for the flag.  I am going through the answers present in the linked question.