# Removing Elements from vector the amount of time it occurs in R

Tags: r, vector

I want to remove the elements from a vector the amount of time it occurs in my other vector. Like if I would substracting them. Given that every element in my vector of elements I want to remove is also existing in the main vector i want to remove from.

```
a <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
b <- c("A", "B", "C", "C")

a[! a %in% b] #returns character(0)

#expected result = "B" "C"
```

I don't want to use a library for this. I'd rather write a function if possible without loops. Is there a way to do so? Thank you in advance

Comment: Very possibly a duplicate of ["Set Difference" between two vectors with duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941312/set-difference-between-two-vectors-with-duplicate-values)

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the most efficient, but

```r
Reduce(function(prev, this) {
  ind <- match(this, prev)
  if (length(ind)) prev[-ind[1]] else prev
}, b, init = a)
# [1] "B" "C"
```

For fun, here's a non-`Reduce` variant (motivated by looking at AllanCameron's simpler answer) that preserves order. The added complexity is only worth it if preserving order is necessary.

```r
finddiff2 <- function(A, B) {
  dict <- split(seq_along(A), A)
  tb <- table(B)
  nms <- intersect(names(tb), A)
  dict[nms] <- Map(tail, dict[nms], -tb[nms])
  A[sort(unlist(dict))]
}
finddiff2(a, b)
# [1] "B" "C"
finddiff2(rev(a), b)
# [1] "C" "B"
finddiff2(c("A","B"), "A")
# [1] "B"
```

The preservation is easier to see with a longer `a`:

```r
a <- rep(c("A","B","C"), times = 4)
finddiff2(a, b)
# [1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C"
finddiff2(rev(a), b)
# [1] "B" "A" "C" "B" "A" "C" "B" "A"
```

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean about the preserved ordering now. Thanks for the addition.

Comment: Try: `finddiff2(c("A", "B"), "A")`

Comment: Good find, fixed @GKi

Comment: Maybe `A[sort(unlist(dict))]` instead of `rep(names(dict), lengths(dict))[order(unlist(dict))]`? To keep also the type (will e.g. work also with integer and will not convert to charter).

Comment: @GKi, that's a great point and recommendation, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

in base R you could use `pmatch`:

```
a[-pmatch(b, a, 0)]
[1] "B" "C"
```

Note that in the above `0` is needed in case there was a value/level in `b` that does not exist in `a`

If all the elements in `b` are in `a` then the following is sufficient

```
a[-pmatch(b, a)]
[1] "B" "C"
```

## NB

as [@jblood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818014/removing-elements-from-vector-the-amount-of-time-it-occurs-in-r/75818462?noredirect=1#comment133750525_75818462) pointed out, `pmatch` only works with [vectors whose length is less than 100](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d29fd8b7f3221aaef97f0980108a230623274442/src/main/unique.c#L1603)

Comment: This should come with a strong caveat of `length(a) < 101 | length(b) < 101`. Otherwise the result will be incorrect. Compare `pmatch(rep("a", 100), rep("a", 100))` to `pmatch(rep("a", 101), rep("a", 101))`.

Comment: @jblood94 so far I do not know as to why that is the case, though the behaviour is quite striking. The only thing i have found so far is the notion that [the target is not allowed to be long](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d29fd8b7f3221aaef97f0980108a230623274442/src/main/unique.c#L1537)

Comment: Line 1603: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d29fd8b7f3221aaef97f0980108a230623274442/src/main/unique.c#L1602

Comment: @jblood94 Thats right. I missed that. haha. yes yes, it shows that both need to be less than 100 otherwise `pmatch` would just change to `charmatch` and not allow multiple exact matches

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a simple function, you could do:

```r
finddiff <- function(a, b) {
  levs <- unique(c(a, b))
  tab  <- table(factor(a, levs)) - table(factor(b, levs))
  tab  <- abs(tab[tab != 0])
  rep(names(tab), tab)
}

finddiff(a, b)
#> [1] "B" "C"
```

Comment: I thought about subtracting tables like that, nice approach. The only advantage `Reduce` has is that it preserves order, which I feared (without verification) that `table(.) - table(.)` would not. Nice use of `factor` in there, btw.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. The ordering in tables is based on factor levels, so we are guaranteed to get matching tables as long as we specify that a and b are factors with the same levels harvested from the unique values of both vectors. I never thought to use Reduce, but it's a neat idea too.

Comment: `finddiff` doesn't preserve order when the letters are not sorted, but the OP never stated that as a requirement, I assumed it (for the challenge).

Comment: Maybe `tab[tab > 0]` instead of `abs(tab[tab != 0])`

Comment: @GKi I guess it depends on what you are trying to extract. `tab[tab > 0]` would get all elements of `a` not in `b`, i.e. **A - B** but `abs(tab[tab != 0])` gets all elements of `a` and `b` that are not part of the intersection, i.e. **A∪B - A∩B**. Both are the same in this example of course, so the OP's aim was open to interpretation.

Comment: I would interpret *I want to remove the elements* as `A - B`. But yes with: *Given that every element in my vector of elements I want to remove is also existing in the main vector i want to remove from.* it will not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `data.table` anti-join with `rowid`:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(a, rowid(a))[!data.table(b, rowid(b)), on = .(a = b, V2)][[1]]
#> [1] "B" "C"
```

---

Testing it on larger vectors:

```
set.seed(2041082007)
a <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(2e5, 2)
b <- sample(a, 1e5)
system.time(ab1 <- data.table(a, rowid(a))[!data.table(b, rowid(b)), on = .(a = b, V2)][[1]])
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.00    0.02    0.01
```

Compare to the `pmatch` solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75818462/9463489) answer:

```
system.time(ab2 <- a[-pmatch(b, a, 0)])
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   46.53    0.00   46.56
```

Additionally, `pmatch` does not seem to behave correctly for this problem:

```
all.equal(ab1, ab2)
#> [1] "Lengths (100000, 196156) differ (string compare on first 100000)"
#> [2] "99979 string mismatches"
```

`pmatch` is returning a much larger vector than expected. Get the difference between the two answers:

```
ab12 <- data.table(ab2, rowid(ab2))[!data.table(ab1, rowid(ab1)), on = .(ab2 = ab1, V2)][[1]]
```

Check what is happening with the first element of `ab12`.

```
ab12[1]
#> [1] "28"
sum(a == ab12[1])
#> [1] 57
sum(b == ab12[1])
#> [1] 45
```

"28" appears 57 times in `a` and 45 times in `b`, so the result should have 12 instances of "28" as was returned by the anti-join.

```
sum(ab1 == ab12[1])
#> [1] 12
```

The `pmatch` solution, however, erroneously returns a vector that has 56 instances of "28".

```
sum(ab2 == ab12[1])
#> [1] 56
```

Comment: `pmatch` will also match parts of a string, but this should not be a problem when as given in the question: *Every element in my vector of elements I want to remove is also existing in the main vector I want to remove*.

Comment: At first I was thinking it had to do with partial matching, but it doesn't seem to be the case. It seems to have to do with the vector sizes. Try `set.seed(1); a <- sample(LETTERS, 1e3, 1); b <- sample(a, 5e2, 1); ab <- a[-pmatch(b, a, 0)]; sum(a == "A"); sum(b == "A"); sum(ab == "A")`.

Comment: @GKi, on the other hand, it seems to work ok for smaller vectors: `set.seed(1); a <- sample(LETTERS, 200, 1); b <- sample(a, 100, 1); ab <- a[-pmatch(b, a, 0)]; sum(a == "A"); sum(b == "A"); sum(ab == "A")`.

Comment: Yes you are right! `pmatch(rep("a", 100), rep("a", 100))` works in my case, while `pmatch(rep("a", 101), rep("a", 101))` does not.

Comment: Yep. 101 seems to be the transition point. I'm trying to find the .Internal code for `pmatch`, but I'm having a hard time.

Comment: Maybe because it "comes from" *argument matching* and typical there are less than 100 arguments...?

Comment: See line 1603 here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d29fd8b7f3221aaef97f0980108a230623274442/src/main/unique.c

Answer (score 0):

```
c <- data.frame(table(a) - table(b))
tidyr::uncount(c, Freq)$a
```

Result

```
[1] B C
Levels: A B C
```