Given two vectors, how to find that the vector A is a subset of the vector B, including the repeated values?
In other words: how to check that all elements of one vector are present in another one, whereby the same element cannot be matched more than once. The question is very simple and yet, I could not find the answer. Let's take an example:
U<-c("a","a","a","b","u")
V<-c("a","a","u")
W<-c("a","b","b")

Here, all elements of V are in the U vector: two "a"'s of three and one "u". The elements of W do not match completely with the vector U, since W has two "b"'s and U has only one.
Note that the %in% function fails here since it ignores multiple occurences of the same element.
I am looking for the standard method of performing this task in R, preferably a built-in.
Here is a workaround I have made:
`%w%` <- \(x,y){
tx <- table(x)
all(table(y)[names(tx)] >= tx)
}

> V %w% U
[1] TRUE
> W %w% U
[1] FALSE


Related Q&As here and here.

The table approach is really cool and it's what I thought while reading the question.

I'm not aware of a standard method.
Here is a modification of your solution wrapping the last line with isTRUE() in case x has elements not presented in y
foo <- function(x, y) {
  #' do all element in x have a corresponding element in y
  freq_x <- table(x)
  isTRUE(all(freq_x <= table(y)[names(freq_x)]))
}

foo(V,U) # TRUE
foo(W,U) # FALSE

A faster alternative:
foo <- function(x, y) {
  #' do all element in x have a corresponding element in y
  x <- factor(x)
  y <- factor(y, levels = levels(x))
  all(tabulate(x) <= tabulate(y, nbins = nlevels(y))) 
}

Benchmarks (medium-sized data):
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  grepl = {grepl(paste(sort(V), collapse = "[b-z]*"), paste(sort(U), collapse = ""))},
  foo_tabulate(V, U),
  foo_table(V, U),
  !length(vsetdiff(V, U)),
  dupsubset(V, U),
  !anyNA(pmatch(V, U))
)
# Unit: microseconds
#                     expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#                    grepl 1758.8 1778.55 1813.338 1788.55 1817.20 2207.3   100
#       foo_tabulate(V, U)   64.2   68.70   72.724   70.95   75.55  110.0   100
#          foo_table(V, U)  179.0  185.00  198.823  192.25  200.45  357.5   100
#  !length(vsetdiff(V, U))  306.0  317.10  334.126  325.60  343.20  502.3   100
#          dupsubset(V, U)  180.1  184.90  197.321  192.15  201.30  381.4   100
#     !anyNA(pmatch(V, U))   14.7   16.95   18.642   17.95   19.35   54.3   100

Benchmarks (big'ish data):
V <- sample(letters, size = 1e3, replace = TRUE)
U <- sample(letters, size = 1e6, replace = TRUE)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  grepl = {grepl(paste(sort(V), collapse = "[b-z]*"), paste(sort(U), collapse = ""))},
  foo_tabulate(V, U),
  foo_table(V, U),
  !length(vsetdiff(V, U)),
  dupsubset(V, U),
  !anyNA(pmatch(V, U)),
  times = 1L
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#                    grepl 5811.0967 5811.0967 5811.0967 5811.0967 5811.0967 5811.0967     1
#       foo_tabulate(V, U)   16.1929   16.1929   16.1929   16.1929   16.1929   16.1929     1
#          foo_table(V, U)  108.6900  108.6900  108.6900  108.6900  108.6900  108.6900     1
#  !length(vsetdiff(V, U))   43.7719   43.7719   43.7719   43.7719   43.7719   43.7719     1
#          dupsubset(V, U)  549.9231  549.9231  549.9231  549.9231  549.9231  549.9231     1
#     !anyNA(pmatch(V, U)) 3306.9685 3306.9685 3306.9685 3306.9685 3306.9685 3306.9685     1


thanks for the improvement! I haven't considered that it could generate some NA's

@ThomasIsCoding it seems factor isn't that bad: see benchmark.

Great answers, +1. I would try the benchmark on larger vectors too, because I don't think my answer scales well, esp. for vectors with a length over 100 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75818462/13460602)

Probably you can use vecsets packages if you are a fan of code-golfing, for example
> library(vecsets)

> !length(vsetdiff(V, U))
[1] TRUE

> !length(vsetdiff(W, U))
[1] FALSE


With base R, you can define a custom function, for example
dupsubset <- function(x, y) {
  yy <- y[y %in% x]
  lvls <- unique(c(x, yy))
  all(table(factor(yy, lvls)) >= table(factor(x, lvls)))
}

or
dupsubset <- function(x, y) {
  xx <- table(x)
  yy <- table(y)
  sum(yy[names(xx)] >= xx, na.rm = TRUE) == length(xx)
}

or
dupsubset <- function(x, y) {
  sum(!is.na(match(make.unique(as.character(y)), make.unique(as.character(x))))) == length(x)
}

such that
> dupsubset(V, U)
[1] TRUE

> dupsubset(W, U)
[1] FALSE


A fast collapse solution:
library(collapse)
all(fsum(rep(c(1, -1), c(length(y), length(x))), c(y, x)) >= 0)


Benchmarking a few solutions with a larger dataset. First check V against U.
library(data.table)
library(vecsets)

set.seed(1282635799L)
U <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(1e5, 2)
V <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(25e3, 2)
W <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(25e3, 2)

which(!c(
  all(table(U)[names(tbl <- table(V))] >= tbl),
  !anyNA(pmatch(V, U)), # incorrect!
  all(tabulate(x <- factor(V)) <= tabulate(y <- factor(U, levels(x)), nlevels(y))),
  all(fsum(rep(c(1, -1), c(length(U), length(V))), c(U, V)) >= 0),
  !data.table(V, rowid(V))[!data.table(U, rowid(U)), on = .(V = U, V2), .N],
  !length(vsetdiff(V, U))
))
#> [1] 2

Note that pmatch fails with the larger dataset as noted in the comments to that answer.
bench::mark(
  table = all(table(U)[names(tbl <- table(V))] >= tbl),
  tabulate = all(tabulate(x <- factor(V)) <= tabulate(y <- factor(U, levels(x)), nlevels(y))),
  collapse = all(fsum(rep(c(1, -1), c(length(U), length(V))), c(U, V)) >= 0),
  data.table = !data.table(V, rowid(V))[!data.table(U, rowid(U)), on = .(V = U, V2), .N],
  vecsets = !length(vsetdiff(V, U))
)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 table       27.84ms   29.1ms     33.9        8MB     5.97
#> 2 tabulate    13.22ms   13.6ms     70.9     2.39MB     3.94
#> 3 collapse     1.41ms   2.06ms    424.      3.02MB    41.8 
#> 4 data.table  12.27ms  12.67ms     74.3     5.51MB    13.7 
#> 5 vecsets    533.31ms 533.31ms      1.88  742.13MB    46.9

Check W against U.
which(c(
  all(table(U)[names(tbl <- table(W))] >= tbl),
  !anyNA(pmatch(W, U)),
  all(tabulate(x <- factor(W)) <= tabulate(y <- factor(U, levels(x)), nlevels(y))),
  all(fsum(rep(c(1, -1), c(length(U), length(W))), c(U, W)) >= 0),
  !data.table(W, rowid(W))[!data.table(U, rowid(U)), on = .(W = U, V2), .N],
  !length(vsetdiff(W, U))
))
#> integer(0)

bench::mark(
  table = all(table(U)[names(tbl <- table(W))] >= tbl),
  tabulate = all(tabulate(x <- factor(W)) <= tabulate(y <- factor(U, levels(x)), nlevels(y))),
  collapse = all(fsum(rep(c(1, -1), c(length(U), length(W))), c(U, W)) >= 0),
  data.table = !data.table(W, rowid(W))[!data.table(U, rowid(U)), on = .(W = U, V2), .N],
  vecsets = !length(vsetdiff(W, U))
)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 table       29.22ms  40.27ms     24.1        8MB     5.57
#> 2 tabulate    13.54ms  16.85ms     57.2     2.39MB     5.91
#> 3 collapse     1.32ms   2.02ms    353.      3.02MB    49.9 
#> 4 data.table  12.38ms  14.03ms     58.5     5.51MB    11.7 
#> 5 vecsets    576.17ms 576.17ms      1.74  742.13MB    36.4


nice1!  I get a slight speed up using integers, i.e. rep(c(1L, -1L)....

And maybe a little more with rep.int.

Edit
This is basically a 'not as good' version of this answer to this similar question. There, @CPak uses a delimiter in the regex (grepl(paste(vec5, collapse="-.*"), paste(vec7, collapse="-")) ) which would be required if the items in the vector are short strings (e.g. "abc" instead of "a") to avoid partial matches.

A regex approach could work depending on your actual use-case, e.g.
U<-c("a","a","a","b","u")
V<-c("a","a","u")
W<-c("a","b","b")

grepl(paste(V, collapse = ".*"), paste(U, collapse = ""))
#> [1] TRUE
grepl(paste(W, collapse = ".*"), paste(U, collapse = ""))
#> [1] FALSE

Created on 2024-06-04 with reprex v2.1.0
You might need to sort the vectors first though.

You can use pmatch + anyNA:
`%w%` <- function(x, y) !anyNA(pmatch(x, y))

V %w% U
#[1] TRUE
W %w% U
#[1] FALSE


Great answer! This is almost the perfect solution.

This is good for short vectors, but breaks down when they get longer than 100. Try rep("a", 101) %w% rep("a", 101). (See https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d29fd8b7f3221aaef97f0980108a230623274442/src/main/unique.c#L1603).

Strange that the 100 hardcoded is still there. However, I guess the other big problem of this cool answer is that pmatch performs partial matching, so for instance "a" %w% "ab" returns TRUE.

Another approach using data.table but with a merge:
library(data.table)

dt <- function(x, y) {
  dt_x <- data.table(element = x)[, .N, by = element]
  dt_y <- data.table(element = y)[, .N, by = element]

  merged_dt <- merge(dt_x, dt_y, by = "element", all.x = TRUE, suffixes = c("_x", "_y"))

  merged_dt[is.na(N_y), N_y := 0]

  all(merged_dt$N_x <= merged_dt$N_y)
}

It depends heavily on what the dataset for U and V are, but in terms of time with large datasets, it seems to be in the same league as the other data.table approach and tabulate.
The big downside of this approach is that it requires significantly more memory, which could limit it for extremely large datasets.
However, it also has a huge upside: almost all the computation time is in the first two lines of the function. That means that if you are doing multiple runs against the same vector, you can actually precalculate dt_y and reuse it:

dt <- function(x, dt_y) {
  dt_x <- data.table(element = x)[, .N, by = element]

  merged_dt <- merge(dt_x, dt_y, by = "element", all.x = TRUE, suffixes = c("_x", "_y"))

  merged_dt[is.na(N_y), N_y := 0]

  all(merged_dt$N_x <= merged_dt$N_y)
}


dt_y <- data.table(element = y)[, .N, by = element]

result1 <- dt(x1, dt_y)
result2 <- dt(x2, dt_y)
result3 <- dt(x3, dt_y)
...


If x and y are roughly the same size, this means that after that initial setup, all calls to the function will be roughly twice as fast. If y is an order of magnitude larger than x, then calls to the function will be about 10x faster. And so on.
This precalculation may or may not work for other answers; I haven't checked.

Using base R. I actually like the table solution, but if you wanted something a bit more terse, you can use make.unique and then it's basically the %in% solution.:
`%w%` <- \(x,y){
  all(make.unique(x) %in% make.unique(y))
}

Test cases:
> V %w% U
[1] TRUE
> W %w% U
[1] FALSE
> rep("a", 101) %w% rep("a", 101)
[1] TRUE

However, it fails for the following case:
> c("A", "A.1") %w% c("A", "A")
[1] TRUE

So I would actually use the table solution if you don't know for certain that elements can't take the form .*\.\d. You could, of course, use the sep argument to guarantee this to work, but then either you lose conciseness, the intent becomes obscured, and/or you will probably hit some arbitrary limitation somewhere.
Example:
`%w%` <- \(x,y){
  # By definition appending this to any member of x or y will result in a new element.
  sep <- paste(c(x, y), collapse = "")
  all(make.unique(x, sep = sep) %in% make.unique(y, sep = sep))
}


